# Element on a menu not responding to a trigger event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made a menu that reveals a drop down menu when you click or touch it. At least that's what happens when you select the word 'Menu2' but unfortunately it's not what happens when you select the words 'Menu3'.

On Menu3, for some reason my code is not recognising the selection of the anchor element and then as a consequence the id of that anchor element is not being passed to the functions which will make the sub-menu appear and disappear.

The strangest thing is that when I replace the 'else if' statement with an 'if' statement the menu under 'Menu2' will appear when I select 'Menu3'!

The thing I took from this was that the querySelectorAll method and the For loop are working. It remains a mystery me why the third menu choice can't be selected.

My question is can anyone work why the menu below 'Menu3' is not opening and closing?

The listeners in the javascript code are activated when the window is loaded.

```js
var timeout = 500;
var closetimer = 0;
var ddmenuitem = 0;

function listen(elem, evnt, func) {
  if (elem.addEventListener) { //W3C DOMS.
    elem.addEventListener(evnt, func, false);
  } else if (elem.attachEvent) { //IE DOM 7
    var r = elem.attachEvent("on" + evnt, func);
    return r;
  }
}

function attachListeners() {
  var selectors = document.querySelectorAll("a#a2, a#a3");

  for (var i = 0; i < selectors.length; i++) {
    selectors[i].addEventListener("focus", function(event) {
      var id_of_clicked_element = event.target.id
    });

    if (id_of_clicked_element = 'a2') {
      var touch_div = document.getElementById(id_of_clicked_element);
      // return false;
    } else if (id_of_clicked_element = 'a3') {
      touch_div = document.getElementById(id_of_clicked_element);
      //return false;   
    }
  }
  
  listen(touch_div, 'touchstart', function(event) {
    // get new layer and show it
    event.preventDefault();
    mopen(id_of_clicked_element);
  }, false);

  listen(touch_div, 'mouseover', function(event) {
    // get new layer and show it
    mopen(id_of_clicked_element);  
  }, false);

  listen(touch_div, 'click', function(event) {
    // get new layer and show it
    mopen(id_of_clicked_element);
  }, false);
}

function m1View() {
  var y = document.getElementById('m1');
  if (y.style.visibility === 'hidden') {
    y.style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    y.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}

function m2View() {
  var z = document.getElementById('m2');
  if (z.style.visibility === 'hidden') {
    z.style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    z.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}

// open hidden layer
function mopen(x) { // get new layer and show it
  var openmenu = x;

  if (openmenu = 'a2') {
    m1View();
  } else if (openmenu = 'a3') {
    m2View();
  }
}

window.onload = attachListeners;
```

```css
#ddm {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 30
}

#ddm li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  font: bold 14px arial
}

#ddm li a {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 12px 17px;
  width: 130px;
  background: #CC0066;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none
}

#ddm li a:hover {
  background: #CC0066
}

#ddm div {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #EAEBD8;
  border: 1px solid #5970B2
}

#ddm div a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 130px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #EAEBD8;
  color: #5C124A;
  font: 13px arial;
  border: 1px solid #CC0066
}

#ddm div a:hover {
  background: #CC0066;
  color: #FFF
}
```

```html
<ul id="ddm">
  <li><a href="#" id="a1">Menu1</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="a2">Menu2</a>
    <div id="m1">
      <a href="#"> Dropdown 1.1 </a>
      <a href="#"> Dropdown 1.2 </a>
      <a href="#"> Dropdown 1.3 </a>
      <a href="#"> Dropdown 1.4 </a>
      <a href="#"> Dropdown 1.5 </a>
      <a href="#"> Dropdown 1.6 </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="a3">Menu3</a>
    <div id="m2">
      <a href="#">Menu4</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" id="a4">Menu5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="a5">Menu6</a></li>
</ul>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

A JSfiddle can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/Webfeet/z9x6Ly6k/27/

Thank you for any help anyone can provide.

NewWeb

Comment: I think you've made your dropdown menu too complicated... and here is another bug I've found.  When you first hover your menu 2, there is no responses, but the second time works.  Not sure if that is what you want to design... (testing on Safari 11.1 via your snippet)

Comment: Hi Leo thanks for looking. You are right it is probably a bit complicated. I am still learning to make menus. I started out wanting the menu to not only respond to modern browsers  but some of the old IE versions as well and yet still be made using event listeners. Thanks for pointing out the bug with the menu not firing first time. I'm not sure why it is doing that. You are right that is unintentional. I have an inline version. I may have to just use that but many commentators on here say don't use the inline method and stick to using event listeners.

Comment: Yeah, I will say event listeners is must modern... and IMO, IE is really die for good.  Let's just forget about it... unless you are facing with those stubborn internet senior.  After all, those IE people are really rare, so it is not worth to put so much effort on it so that we can be more productive.

Comment: Do you think many users would notice the menu doesn't fire straight away upon load? Once they get it going they may not notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a couple of things.  First, like Leo Li suggested, I think you may have overcomplicated this a little.  For instance, you could replace your attachListeners function with something like this:

```
function attachListeners() {
    var selectors = document.querySelectorAll("a#a2, a#a3");

    for (var i = 0; i < selectors.length; i++) {
        selectors[i].addEventListener('touchstart', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            mopen(event.target.id);
        }, false);

        selectors[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            mopen(event.target.id);
        }, false);

        selectors[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            mopen(event.target.id);
        }, false);
    }
}
```

But, besides that, one of the biggest problems is in the mopen() function.  Instead of checking the value being passed in for *x*, you're reassigning it. Just switch the equals signs with triple equals, like this:

```
  if (openmenu === 'a2') {
    m1View();
  } else if (openmenu === 'a3') {
    m2View();
  }
```

It's still probably not quite what you're looking for but here's a fork of your JSfiddle with my changes - https://jsfiddle.net/n90ryvfd/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Brian thanks for showing me this it was a revelation on two fronts. The simplification and the assignment issue. My next task is to try and stop both menus opening at the same time. You and Leo were right I had over complicated things too much. I set out to use event listeners but they do seem to add a layer of complication with functions everywhere.

Comment: I was able to add some cross browser support for older versions by weaving it into the code you suggested. I may never find out if it actually works on older browsers but it didn't fall over when I ran the code.